# Is there a better way to parse a dynamic value of a Django Template into a Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-templates

Is there a better method to retrieve the dynamic value 'bar' from the Django Template?

index.html:

```
<div id="foo" name="{{bar}}"></div>
```

main.js:

```
const foo = document.getElementById('foo')
const bar = foo.name
console.log(bar)
```

output:

```
bar
```

Comment: what's wrong with your solution? it looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorite ways is to use `data` attributes and accessing them in jQuery using `$("<identifier>").data("<variable_name>")`.

Another way is to have a block before loading the `main.js` file (or after if you check for document load (`.on("load")`) before accessing any values) and in the template, using that block, define a dictionary object using custom values. I also used it for custom autocompletes in the front-end where connected values are already defined (example: selecting size according to a color of a product).

```html
{% block custom_js %}
<script type="text/javascript">
let variables = {foo_name: "{{ bar }}"}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Your way will also be fine, and also very common.